# Can't figure out WHY this UPDATE statement is running

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

Running in Sql Server 2008 R2, here is my UPDATE statement, which is being run in an AFTER INSERT trigger:

```
UPDATE cases.CASEMASTER
SET    HOLDLETTERSUNTIL = '1/1/9999'
FROM   cases.CASEMASTER C
       JOIN INSERTED I
         ON I.CASEID = C.ROWID
       JOIN events.EVENTLIBRARY L
         ON L.ROWID = I.DEFINITIONID
WHERE  L.HOLDLETTERS = 1
       AND C.HOLDLETTERSUNTIL < GETDATE()
```

The joins are all correct, and via the output window, I have confirmed that the where conditions evaluate - in order - to FALSE and TRUE.

And yet for some reason I cannot fathom, this statement is actually running and attempting to fire off the UPDATE. Since the first WHERE condition is FALSE, I cannot for the life of me figure why this is UPDATING any rows in cases.CASEMASTER. But I know for fact that it is, because it is firing off a trigger on that table.

Am I missing something stupidly obvious staring me in the face, that is bypassing my WHERE clause?

The EVENTLIBRARY.HOLDLETTERS is an INT field that can be -1, 0, or 1, specifying whether a particular event should UNHOLD, NOTCHANGE, or HOLD letters when it is logged against a case.

CASEMASTER.HOLDLETTERUNTIL is a DATE field.

The table being inserted into is EVENTMASTER, which defines the actual events logged against a case.

CASEMASTER > EVENTMASTER is 1-N
EVENTMASTER > EVENTLIBRARY is N-1

And, Now I am REALLY confused! It IS firing off the 2nd trigger. But the 2nd trigger's INSERTED table has ZERO rows in it. So it seems that Sql Server fires a trigger just because the triggering event was run, even though no rows were actually changed? Is this something new? I was always under the assumption that if there were no rows changed, then an AFTER UPDATE trigger would not fire.

Comment: Does it actually update with new values records for which condition is false?

Comment: You are telling us that there is no row that has `events.EVENTLIBRARY.HOLDLETTERS = 1` and yet the query updates some rows in the `cases.CASEMASTER` table?

Comment: Yes, I am manually testing it with a single-row insert of hard-coded values. And I am specifically using a EVENTID for which `HOLDLETTERS = 0`, and yet it is updating cases.CASEMASTER. I am totally baffled.

Comment: The update *tries* to run, or the query successfully updates rows? In the question you just complain about it "attempting to fire off the UPDATE" but it is not clear what the actual outcome is...

Comment: What is the datatype for `HOLDLETTERS` column ? What is the relationship between `CASEMASTER` table and `inserted` / `EVENTLIBRARY` ? One to many, many yo one, one to one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what `EVENTID` has to do with anything, given that I don't see `EVENTID` mentioned in the query at all. Perhaps you are joining on more rows than you thought because you have left out a join condition - I presume there is at least one row in `EVENTLIBRARY` with `HOLDLETTERS = 1`, even if it has a different `EVENTID` than the current row(s) being updated, or a different `DEFINITIONID` than the one mentioned in your query. I don't know what the actual query should be because I don't the schema and inter-table relationships.

Also:

```
UPDATE C SET HOLDLETTERSUNTIL = '1/1/9999' 
     --^-- this...
FROM cases.CASEMASTER C --<-- ...should match this
```

And finally, your assumption that a trigger only fires when 1 or more rows is actually affected is false. A trigger fires for every relevant statement, even if no rows are actually affected. Easy example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

-- simple, empty table:

CREATE TABLE dbo.flab(i INT);
GO

-- simple table that just prints a message:

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trFlab
ON dbo.flab FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  PRINT 'See?';
END
GO

-- this query affects zero rows, both because the WHERE condition is false
-- and also because there are are no rows in the table to begin with!

UPDATE dbo.flab SET i = 1 WHERE 1 = 2;
```

But the results show that the trigger was fired:

```
See?

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Typically you check if any rows are actually affected in a trigger by:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
```

and/or

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
```

Your second trigger is probably not doing anything like that before announcing that it has fired.

So, rather than jump to the conclusion that rows are being updated because a trigger is fired on the second table, you should actually check to see if those rows were updated. Unless your join conditions are wrong (and I suspect something is fishy there, since you mentioned a column in a comment that isn't mentioned in the code), I suspect this isn't true and what you think is happening is not what is actually happening.

UPDATE:

> So it seems that Sql Server fires a trigger just because the triggering event was run, even though no rows were actually changed? Is this something new?

That is absolutely what happens, and it is absolutely not new. From the very first note in [the SQL Server 2005 documentation for `CREATE TRIGGER`, last updated in July of 2006](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

> These triggers fire when any valid event is fired, regardless of whether or not any table rows are affected. This is by design.

Comment: AHHH - okay, you just answered my updated Q. A trigger fires EVEN IF no rows were actually affected. That just seems REALLY odd to me, but ... it is what it is. Now I just have to recode to deal with that. Thanks!!!

Comment: This is why the SQL Server UPDATE triggers give you pseudo-tables INSERTED/DELETED to base your procedure on.  An empty INSERTED table (zero rows) may be the easily implemented quick return you need to speed things up.  In some situations a cursor over the INSERTED table (possibly joined to other tables) will give better performance than the unitary UPDATE statement used in your current approach.